# Where in Laravel 5 should I place initial service providers calls?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Where in Laravel should I place initial service providers calls?

Here is an example:

```
    \Socialite::extend('github', function($app) {
        $config = $app['config']['services.github'];
        return new \App\Socialite\EmailGithubProvider(
            $app['request'], $config['client_id'],
            $config['client_secret'], $config['redirect']
        );
    });
```

Where should I place this code? What's the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your bootstrapping code in a Service Provider.

Running `php artisan make:provider SocialiteExtensionsServiceProvider` will make you one at `app/Providers/SocialiteExtensionsServiceProvider.php`.

For extending Laravel's manager classes (as you are), place your code in the Provider's `boot()` method. For IoC bindings, place them in `register()`.

Then, add your provider to the list of providers in `config/app.php`

Comment: If I do this, there is an error: `Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable.`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Manager extensions (as this is) should be done in the `boot()` method, not `register()`. Updating my answer.